# Magento1.9 :404 not found error

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.4

My magento site is 1.9 version. We upgraded the php version to 7.4. After upgrading php version most of the pages in the website coming as 404 error only for particular one store. Any idea on this why it is getting.

Comment: Did you forget turn on the url_rewite ?

Comment: @RintoGeorge can u plz explain again...am not getting ur point

Comment: Magento' url heavily relies more_rewrite module? Quick question which server you are using Ngnix or Apache?

Comment: @RintoGeorge  apache

Comment: Do you have a link for your website?